# Cant run "ls" command from python cgi

Tags: python, linux, apache, cgi

I have a Apache2 server which is able to run python(.py) cgi.

everytime i try to run:

```
print subprocess.call(['ls'])
```

I am getting a "500 Internal Server Error"
error log:

```
[cgid:error] [pid 26234:tid 139903652325120] [client 10.200.8.23:55682] malformed header from script 'newpw.py': Bad header: newpw.py
```

but when i run "date" as the parameter everything works fine. (Is returning 1)
print subprocess.call(['date'])

thats my whole script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import cgitb
    import subprocess

    cgitb.enable()

    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print

    print subprocess.call(['ls'])
```

Thanks

Comment: are you sure your `.py` is executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if your `.py` is executable.
If not, change it by `chmod +x newpw.py`

also, try adding new lines to your header:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
```

at the end, try flush the stdout before subprocess call:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
print subprocess.call(['ls'])
```

Comment: have you tried even adding new lines after header, and not working?

Comment: strange, is that problem from your `path` environment settings? try `subprocess.call('/bin/ls')`?

Comment: OK, try to flush the stdout before the call? `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: @RaverTiny, since everything else didn't work, so guessing probably your message is served as buffer. so a stdout flush could help this.